# Require that k8s pods have a certain label before they run on certain nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kube-scheduler

Say I have some special nodes in my cluster, and I want to be able to identify with a pod label all pods running on these nodes.

Taints & tolerations are close to this, but afaik tolerations aren’t labels, they’re their own thing, and can’t be referenced in places where you expect a label selector, right? Is there any way to require all pods running on these nodes to identify themselves in a way that can then be queried via label selectors?

Comment: Yes taints and tolerations are their own thing completely different from labels. They have their own function during a scheduling cycle. To answer your question: Apply a taint to the node. Apply a label to the node. Add this taint's toleration to pods. Add the nodeSelector to the pod. Query pods by node rather than a label. Would this work?

Comment: Sort of, except nothing requires that the label need to be on the pod if it's running on that node. We can do this by convention, but I was hoping for a way to force it, so that nothing could run on these nodes without getting this label.

But it seems like I might need to bite the bullet and use a custom webhook admission controller to ensure the label is there?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://gmaslowski.com/kubernetes-node-label-to-pod/) as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts of problem to solve:
**1. Ensure that pods with specific labels are scheduled to specific set of nodes.**
This can be done by using custom scheduler or a plugin for default scheduler (more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/), [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduling-framework/), [here](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/containers/articles/creating-a-custom-kube-scheduler/), [here](https://github.com/IBM/k8s-custom-scheduler) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/scheduler-plugins)).

**2. Prevent other schedulers to schedule pods to that nodes**
This can by achieved by using `nodeAffinity` or node taints (more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-isolation-restriction) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/))

A complete solution may require additional apiserver admission controller to set all those properties to a pod that suppose to have a specific label only.
Unfortunately, there is no easy built-in solution as of yet. Hopefuly the above will point you in the right direction.